# Convergence in distribution - approaching 1?

Tags: self-study, distributions, convergence

Can I say that the fact that a sequence of random variables $X_n $  converges in distribution to a random variable $\ X $  means that the probability that the realizations of $X_n $ are arbitrarily close to the realizations of $X $ approaches 1 as $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: I recommend consulting the definitions.  In the meantime, please consider elaborating on what you mean by "the realizations of..." and by "arbitrarily close," because neither of those seem pertinent to convergence of random variables or of distributions.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is negative.

A counterexample: let $Y \sim N(0, 1)$ and let $X_n = Y, \forall n = 1, \ldots$, and let $X = -Y$.

Then $-Y$ has the same distribution as $Y$ and thus $X_n \rightarrow_d X$. However, the realizations of $X_n$ do not approach that of $X$ in the sense that the probability $P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon)$ does not approach zero for any $\epsilon > 0$. To see this, note that the distribution of $|X_n - X|$, and thus  the value of $P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon)$, is actually the same for all $n$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the realizations ... do not approach," in light of the fact that there is no possible way you could distinguish a realization of $X$ from one of $-X$?

Answer (score -1):

$X_n \rightarrow_d X$ if $F_X{_d} \rightarrow F_X$. Can't $X$, $Y$ IID RVs assume two different vals but have the same DF? What is the counterexample to that?